# How to resolve this error, ARCGIS JSAPI

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/info?f=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm getting this error. What might be the problem? I'm beginner to ARCGIS JSAPI,

Answer (score 1):

Like @ahammadalipk points out it's a CORS issue and not specific to the JSAPI.

I don't think sampleserver1 supports CORS (it's an old server). Another alternative is to use a proxy. See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

Or maybe take a step back. Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to test with a newer server, either on ArcGIS Online or sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com. Both of those supports CORS. There's an example for the latter: 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/util_relation.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
    require([..],function(...){
esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push(window.location.hostname)
.....
})
```

Comment: Thanks @emredelioglu, I tried with that but still I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the CORS issue, you need to enable JavaScript in sample server,basically server will block JavaScript request unless you give JavaScript permission.